# Using wget with a URL

Tags: command-line, wget

I am trying to get the content of this particular URL using wget command in ubuntu but the message I get is as given below:
http://192.92.176.8/cgi-bin/oindex.mbr/alldetail?Official=N&Birth=N&Death=N&Marriage=N&Maps=N&Fbn=N&USERKEY=2017031500000000000061&Batno=176233&Batsq=1&Cert=2016005450&Last_Rcd=00010&oindex_Name=BANUELOS%20JEFFREY%20GEORGE&Doc_Date=20160202&Counter=1&Doc_Desc=Trust%20Deed&RelDoc=%2E00&TYPE=&Book=&Page=0&APN=&Doc_Type=007&Pages=13&Image=B16033AA.AAB&Path=&Prev_Search=0006%20&P_Stat1=&P_Desc1=&P_Stat2=&P_Desc2=&P_Stat3=&P_Desc3=&P_Stat4=&P_Desc4=&P_Verify=Y&FIRST=Y&Doc_request=SELECT

```
Message:
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<STYLE TYPE="text/css">
#loading { position: absolute }
NET.DATA Error: Function call to DTW_RGETCOOKIE failed.  Error Number is 8000.
```

I am not sure what exactly the problem is.